# 24 bits shifting on PIC16F

Tags: c, pic

I have a problem on one of my shifting.

```
unsigned char intern_key_L;
unsigned char intern_key_ML;
unsigned char intern_key_MH;
unsigned char intern_key_H;

unsigned long intern_key[KEY_MAX];
intern_key[channel] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
intern_key_L = intern_key[channel];
intern_key_ML = intern_key[channel] >> 8;
intern_key_MH = intern_key[channel] >> 16;
intern_key_H =  intern_key[channel] >> 24;
```

asm:

```
Encode.c: 191: intern_key_H = intern_key[channel] >> 24;
movf    ?a_key_compute+8,w
movwf   btemp
bcf     3,0
rlf     btemp
bcf     3,0
rlf     btemp,w
addlw   _intern_key
movwf   4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+1
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+2
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+3
movwf   btemp
clrf    btemp+2
clrf    btemp+1
clrf    btemp
movf    btemp,w
movwf   ?a_key_compute+4
```

`intern_key_H` is equal to 0 and not 0xFF.

But if I do:

```
unsigned char intern_key_L;
unsigned char intern_key_ML;
unsigned char intern_key_MH;
unsigned char intern_key_H;

unsigned long intern_key[KEY_MAX];
unsigned long tmp;

intern_key[channel] = 0xFFFFFFFF;

tmp = intern_key[channel];

intern_key_L = intern_key[channel];
intern_key_ML = intern_key[channel] >> 8;
intern_key_MH = intern_key[channel] >> 16;
intern_key_H =  tmp >> 24;
```

asm :

```
;Encode.c: 191: tmp = intern_key[channel];
movf    ?a_key_compute+8,w
movwf   btemp
bcf 3,0
rlf btemp
bcf 3,0
rlf btemp,w
addlw   _intern_key
movwf   4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+1
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+2
incf    4
movf    0,w
movwf   btemp+3
movf    btemp,w
movwf   ?a_key_compute+9
movf    btemp+1,w
movwf   ?a_key_compute+10
movf    btemp+2,w
movwf   ?a_key_compute+11
movf    btemp+3,w
movwf   ?a_key_compute+12
;Encode.c: 192: intern_key_H = tmp >> 24;
movwf   ?a_key_compute+4
```

This way, `intern_key_H` is equal to 0xFF.

Why the last shifting is not working on the fisrt snippet (the first 3 bytes are OK) ?

It is a PIC16F688, intern_key[KEY_MAX] is in bank1 and compiler is HI-TECH v8.05.

Some

Comment: Your question is missing a question. Don't expect people to guess what you want :)

Comment: Try adding explicit masking, i.e. make each assignment something like `intern_key_ML = (intern_key[channel] >> 8) & 0xff;`.

Comment: What is value of `channel` when you perform the operations?

Comment: I change the second snippet, there was a mistake. It seems that the shift of 24 bits on an array is not working.

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof (unsigned long)` with your compiler and architecture ?

Comment: @zakinster the value is 4

Comment: What is the value of KEY_MAX and channel?  Suspect you have not in range.

Comment: What is the memory address of `intern_key[channel]`? Show anssembler code!

Comment: Either your compiler is broken, `KEY_MAX` <= 0, your determination that `intern_key_H` is 0 is wrong, **or** OP code has other [bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooties)

Comment: @chux KEY_MAX is 1, I'm sure inten_key_H is not 0xFF but I agree that maybe code has other bugs. I will check the assembler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is broken.

It is the  `clrf btemp, movf btemp,w` that is incorrectly zeroing your result.

```
clrf btemp+2, clrf btemp+1, clrf btemp
// should be
clrf btemp+3, clrf btemp+2, clrf btemp+1
// or eliminated.
```

Suggest submit bug report. Use your work around until fixed.
Compiler became confused casting `unsigned long` to `unsigned char` and shifting 24 at the same time.
The `intern_key[channel]` access and `intern_key_H =` assignment are OK.

OP *could* try the following to help flaky compiler to generate the right code.

```
intern_key_H =  (unsigned char) (intern_key[channel] >> 24);
```

Comment: Note: The PIC family is a very dynamic and growing part of the embedded industry with many variant size processors and options.  Unfortunately compiler bugs are too frequent.  Guess that's the price being on this edge of technology.  Look forward to what the makers of "HI-TECH" say.